# Is it possible to replace a not found \cite by a customized text/hyperlink?

Tags: citing

I am working on a documentation library that uses parts of body texts of different documents. Sometimes this text will contain a `\cite` that is found only in the "master version". I would like the compiled version to show a certain text (e.g. a name without a link) instead of "??".

I could not find a way to do this with [cite](http://mirror.ox.ac.uk/sites/ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/cite/cite.pdf) package documentation.

Is this possible to achieve with any external package?

Comment: How are you compiling? With biblatex/biber, I get the citekey in bold as the unresolved cite.

Comment: Not sure about the cite package, but normally one could use `\xpatchcmd` from the xpatch package to replace `?` with `\@citeb`.